# Exception: Assertion at ..., condition '<disabled>' not met. What does that mean?

Tags: azure, google-chrome, blazor, webassembly

I just published to Azure a Blazor Wasm app I am developing with VS Community 2019.  The app starts up successfully in VS, but the published version triggers the exception below (both in Chrome), which gives me no clue as to the problem.  Perhaps a problem with my Azure account?  I've just started to learn what I need to do to publish, now that I'm at a certain point in my development.  I published 2-3 months ago a much simpler early version of the app, which functionally did what's noted below, and it worked at that time.

Curiously, after I first published it a few minutes ago, my console log messages indicated it got through most of my main layout's OnInitializedAsync code, including a JSRuntime.InvokeAsync to my JavaScipt initialization code that opens an IndexedDB and returns its Index of keys.  But when I tried re-publishing and got the same exception, none my initialization code ran according to the console log.  I can post my OnInitializedAsync code, but since the exception is now happening before any of this code executes, I'm not sure it will be helpful.  Any idea what's going on?

Thanks.  Steve

[image]

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same problem, but while publishing to local IIS. Got it working by changing the Deploy Configuration from Release to Debug, but this is not really a fix.

Answer (score 2):

When I ran into this issue it was due to my build pipeline BuildConfiguration setting being set to "debug" instead of "release" inside azure devops.

(EA. Pipelines -> Edit Blazor Web Project Pipeline -> Variables -> Build Configuration -> Release)

[image]